# What is the difference if an url ends with .html

Tags: url, html

I wonder why some of my Magento urls end with .html and others do not.

Why should I end my url with .html and how to remove it if I would like to have a simple/clear url for my customers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **admin->system->Configuration->catalog->catalog-> Search Engine Optimization**

Product URL Suffix remove .html

Category URL Suffix  remove .html

Comment: I also wonder what is the difference. I can not find anything on this topic, only about slash on the end, but not .html.

Comment: It makes no difference at all. Including or not including .html at the end of a URL has no impact at all on your SEO efforts.